# Transpose every 2 columns to new row

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I have got the code for my need but i need little bit of help with it.. this code is working fine for just 1 row but . i am having data on multiple row like 1st is on row A1,A101,A201 and so on... but its not working with multiple lines.. can anybody help. thanks!
in screenshot 1 its the status before running the script.. it takes every 2 columns and put it in new row..  but its NOT running for multiple row... like i have 1 convertable data on row A1 and then the other is on row A101, A201 and so own..

### Input data:

[image: Input data]

```
Sub dividde_16()

    No_of_columns = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    No_of_rows = Int(No_of_columns / 2) + 1

    For i = 1 To No_of_rows
        For j = 1 To 2
            Cells(i + 1, j) = Cells(i * 2 + j)
        Next
    Next
    Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, No_of_columns)) = ""

End Sub
```

### Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to be doing? What does your data look like now, and what do you expect it to look like when the code completes?

Comment: i have just updated the information about code and 2 images

Comment: I think the first thing you should do is remove the white space from rows 2:100, 102:200, etc.

Comment: its already removed Jeeped

Comment: Your number of rows is dependent on the number of columns which it shouldn't be. It should be dependent on the number of rows (e.g counting A1, A101, A201 etc)

Comment: I'm not programmer, i found above code that is closer to my requirement but need some help in edits anyone can assist. thanks

Comment: That is not what your narrative or your code says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a little fun with the code but it is effective.

[image]

```
Sub Columns2ToRows()
    Dim arData()
    Dim colCount As Long, x As Long

    colCount = Columns(Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim arData(0)

    For x = 1 To colCount Step 2
        ReDim Preserve arData(Int(x / 2))
        arData(Int(x / 2)) = Array(Cells(1, x).Value, Cells(1, x + 1).Value)
    Next

    Rows(1).ClearContents

    arData = Application.Transpose(arData)
    arData = Application.Transpose(arData)

    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arData), 2) = arData

End Sub
```

Comment: Great Thanks Tom :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Formulaically you can do it like this with this generic formula:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,0,(ROW()-2)*cols+COLUMN()-1)
```

Where "cols" is the number of columns. This assumes the source data is in row 1 and results start in row 2 as shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with sample data like the following. Note that the <div> tags come in pairs.

[image: linkedin_before]

Run this sub procedure.

```
Sub wqewqwer()
    Dim rw As Long, iCOLs As Long, iROWs As Long
    Dim a As Long, aTMP1 As Variant, aTMP2 As Variant

    With Worksheets("Sheet12")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If CBool(Application.CountBlank(.Cells)) Then
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With

        For rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            aTMP1 = .Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value2
            ReDim aTMP2(1 To Int(UBound(aTMP1, 2) / 2), 1 To 2)
            For a = LBound(aTMP1, 2) To UBound(aTMP1, 2) Step 2
                aTMP2(Int(a / 2) + 1, 1) = aTMP1(1, a)
                aTMP2(Int(a / 2) + 1, 2) = aTMP1(1, a + 1)
            Next a
            .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(aTMP2, 1), 1).EntireRow.Insert
            .Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(aTMP2, 1), UBound(aTMP2, 2)) = aTMP2
            .Range(.Cells(rw, 2), .Cells(rw, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Clear
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: linkedin_after]